# lower_bound/upper_bound on unsorted vector

Tags: c++, stl

```
const std::vector<int> v = {5, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 5, 6};

auto low = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), 7);
auto high = std::upper_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), 7);
std::cout << low - v.begin() << " " << high - v.begin();
```

So when I try to compile this code using the clang++ compiler on my Mac , it returns the output as

```
10 10
```

which implies as `v.end()` for both high and low although low should be = 1 and high =7 (the number 8). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that both [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) requires the range to be "at least partially ordered".

Comment: Those functions only work on *sorted* data.

Comment: And for future questions, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just out of interest, what exactly is wrong with the question? It seems "minimal", "complete", and "verifiable" to me.

Comment: @AliAlamiri We should basically be able to copy-paste the code and replicate the output without any effort to "fix" things. This includes things like header files and `main` function. The output should also be copy-pasted as text, not just written mixed in with the rest of the text. And we should also see the *expected* output, in the same format as the actual output. This is all detailed in the links I provided.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So a valid question is downvoted (which discourages users anyway) because we are incapable of knowing that vector comes from <vector> and to run the code we need to be told that we have to put it in main? Hmm OK, seems odd to me. If the types being used in the question were obscure, then I can slightly see your point (although we can always ask users to include further info rather than down vote), however in this case these requirements are too extreme.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the info, I'll definitely keep in mind

Answer (score 4):

`std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` requires that the range is "sorted" (partitionned according to predicate and given value in fact), which is not your case.

Comment: Can you tell me the mechanism of upper_bound and lower_bound, i mean do they use binary search or anything?

Comment: @TheSYNcoder To understand the mechanism of upper_bound and lower_bound, you can refer to the following links: [upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/), [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/)

Comment: @TheSYNcoder: `std::lower_bound` can be implemented with `std::partition_point`. It indeed does some binary search.